# pandas combining dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

java = pickle.load(open('JavaSafe.p','rb')) ##import 2d array
python = pickle.load(open('PythonSafe.p','rb')) ##import 2d array

javaFrame = pd.DataFrame(java,columns=['Town','Java Jobs'])
pythonFrame = pd.DataFrame(python,columns=['Town','Python Jobs'])
javaFrame = javaFrame.sort_values(by='Java Jobs',ascending=False)
pythonFrame = pythonFrame.sort_values(by='Python Jobs',ascending=False)
print(javaFrame,"\n",pythonFrame)
```

This code comes out with the following:

```
                Town  Java Jobs
435          York,NY       3593
212       NewYork,NY       3585
584       Seattle,WA       2080
624       Chicago,IL       1920
301        Boston,MA       1571
...
79        Holland,MI          5
38      Manhattan,KS          5
497        Vernon,IL          5
30        Clayton,MO          5
90       Waukegan,IL          5

[653 rows x 2 columns] 

                 Town  Python Jobs
160       NewYork,NY         2949
11           York,NY         2938
349       Seattle,WA         1321
91        Chicago,IL         1312
167        Boston,MA         1117

383       Hanover,NH            5
209      Bulverde,TX            5
203     Salisbury,NC            5
67       Rockford,IL            5
256       Ventura,CA            5

[416 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to make a new dataframe that uses the town names as an index and has a column for each java and python.  However, some of the towns will only have results for one of the languages.

Comment: you could also do given your original code `result = pd.merge(pythonFrame, javeFrame, on='Town', how='outer').set_index('Town')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

javaFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Java Jobs': [3593, 3585, 2080, 1920, 1571, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
     'Town': ['York,NY', 'NewYork,NY', 'Seattle,WA', 'Chicago,IL', 'Boston,MA', 'Holland,MI', 'Manhattan,KS', 'Vernon,IL', 'Clayton,MO', 'Waukegan,IL']}, index=[435, 212, 584, 624, 301, 79, 38, 497, 30, 90])
pythonFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Python Jobs': [2949, 2938, 1321, 1312, 1117, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
     'Town': ['NewYork,NY', 'York,NY', 'Seattle,WA', 'Chicago,IL', 'Boston,MA', 'Hanover,NH', 'Bulverde,TX', 'Salisbury,NC', 'Rockford,IL', 'Ventura,CA']}, index=[160, 11, 349, 91, 167, 383, 209, 203, 67, 256])

result = pd.merge(javaFrame, pythonFrame, how='outer').set_index('Town')
#               Java Jobs  Python Jobs
# Town                                
# York,NY          3593.0       2938.0
# NewYork,NY       3585.0       2949.0
# Seattle,WA       2080.0       1321.0
# Chicago,IL       1920.0       1312.0
# Boston,MA        1571.0       1117.0
# Holland,MI          5.0          NaN
# Manhattan,KS        5.0          NaN
# Vernon,IL           5.0          NaN
# Clayton,MO          5.0          NaN
# Waukegan,IL         5.0          NaN
# Hanover,NH          NaN          5.0
# Bulverde,TX         NaN          5.0
# Salisbury,NC        NaN          5.0
# Rockford,IL         NaN          5.0
# Ventura,CA          NaN          5.0
```

---

[`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) will by default join two DataFrames on all columns shared in common. In this case,  `javaFrame` and `pythonFrame` share only the `Town` column in common. So by default `pd.merge` would join the two DataFrames on the `Town` column.

`how='outer` causes `pd.merge` to use the [union of the keys from both frames](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra). In other words it causes `pd.merge` to return rows whose data come from either `javaFrame` or `pythonFrame` even if only one DataFrame contains the `Town`. Missing data is fill with `NaN`s.

Comment: `result = pd.merge(javaFrame, pythonFrame, how='outer').set_index('Town')` is, I think, what they are expecting!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('Town') for df in [javaFrame, pythonFrame]], axis=1)

              Java Jobs  Python Jobs
Boston,MA        1571.0       1117.0
Bulverde,TX         NaN          5.0
Chicago,IL       1920.0       1312.0
Clayton,MO          5.0          NaN
Hanover,NH          NaN          5.0
Holland,MI          5.0          NaN
Manhattan,KS        5.0          NaN
NewYork,NY       3585.0       2949.0
Rockford,IL         NaN          5.0
Salisbury,NC        NaN          5.0
Seattle,WA       2080.0       1321.0
Ventura,CA          NaN          5.0
Vernon,IL           5.0          NaN
Waukegan,IL         5.0          NaN
York,NY          3593.0       2938.0
```